# Can you use CloudPagesUrl() with a Code Resource?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, email, cloudpagesurl

I'd like to provide wrapped links in my emails that direct my subscribers to a CloudPages Code Resource, rather than a conventional landing page. I need to pass personally identifiable data to the Code Resource and I've been looking at the [CloudPagesURL](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/cloudpagesurl.htm) AMPScript function that appears to do exactly what I need. Can you use this function to wrap your links to a Code Resource?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll take that as an invitation ;)
copy paste from my post here:
[Super Messages || LANDING PAGE vs CODE RESOURCE](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/312772/super-messages-landing-page-vs-code-resource)

CloudPagesURL() function works for both Landing Pages and Code Resources. If they are in the same Business Unit as the code employing the function. It's just harder to find the right ID for a Code Resource, as the number shown in the URL is not correct and there is no menu for "page options".

You have two options for a Code Resource:

Option 1: Output the parameter %%=v(@tabId)=%% on the Code resource, and publish it. Access the URL in a browser to see the printed CloudPageID, e.g. 1111. If your Code resource is already live and you cannot simply republish it, then go for option 2):

Option 2: Save your Code Resource. Open another Code Resource; in this one, access the Code Resource Menu on the left and insert your Code Resource, this will show how to access it using CloudPagesURL(); e.g. %%=CloudPagesURL(1111)=%%